# env GTK_THEME cannot apply to the title bar

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk3

I use this command to launch libreoffice:

```
env GTK_THEME=365os-new-blue libreoffice
```

But title bar cannot change to the `365os-new-blue` theme:

[image: LibreOffice]

I want to apply `365os-new-blue` theme to the title too:

[image: LibreOffice]

Opened some other GTK3 applications with that method, all of them have the same problem.

Is there any way to open an application with another theme and have that theme on title bar?